# How do I determine what IAM service account a GKE cluster is using

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

One of my pods needs to access a google storage bucket and I keep getting permission denied. It *appears* as if the permissions are in order. However, I can't find anywhere that the error message explicitly states *which* account is being used, so I'm *theorizing* that it's not using the account I think it is.
How can I determine which account is being used, either by interrogating GKE, or by asking the storage bucket for security audit details, or ... ?

Comment: If the answer below has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command to get the Service Account from your GKE cluster:

```
kubectl get  serviceaccount  -o  yaml
```

You can use this command to get the list of Service Accounts used in your project

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy (your project ID)
```

Additionally, you can follow this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity) to troubleshoot issues if your deployment was created using Workload Identity on your GKE cluster.